# Docker: error while installation

Tags: docker

I try to install Docker to Ubuntu 18.04.

I use this guide:
https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/

At the first time, I passed all steps and got error on last, attempting to install docker-ce:

```
# apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
```

than, installation crushed with error. After that, I tried to install docker once more from the first step:

```
$ sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

and got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package 'docker-engine' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'containerd' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'docker' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'docker.io' is not installed, so not removed
Package 'runc' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 58 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up docker-ce (5:18.09.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
update-alternatives: warning: forcing reinstallation of alternative /usr/bin/dockerd-ce because link group dockerd is broken
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-04-12 13:52:26 MSK; 11ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1884 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1884 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 12 13:52:26 n0ykp.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: docker.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Apr 12 13:52:26 n0ykp.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 12 13:52:26 n0ykp.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--configure):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Please help me to solve problem and install docker.

UPD. After

```
apt purge docker docker-ce docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
```

:

```
root@ovz1:~# dpkg -i /home/xpendence/downloads/docker-ce_18.09.5_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package docker-ce.
(Reading database ... 33991 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../docker-ce_18.09.5_3-0_ubuntu-bionic_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking docker-ce (5:18.09.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
Setting up docker-ce (5:18.09.5~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/dockerd-ce to provide /usr/bin/dockerd (dockerd) in auto mode
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/docker.service → /lib/systemd/system/docker.service.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/docker.socket → /lib/systemd/system/docker.socket.
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "start" failed.
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-04-12 15:27:23 MSK; 11ms ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
  Process: 3938 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3938 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 12 15:27:23 n0ykp.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Apr 12 15:27:23 n0ykp.vps.myjino.ru systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--install):
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.11) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
```

Comment: try `sudo apt purge docker docker-ce docker-engine docker.io containerd runc`

Comment: Please, post the log of `journactl -xe -u docker`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. I would recommend such issues when having regular setup to be reported to upstream project as bug. Its developers have more instruction how to debug and may fix quickly.

Comment: I'm also having this issue... looking for a solution too. Have you had any luck with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. After Ubuntu upgrade from 18.04.4 to 20.04.2 docker would not start, and errored when trying to install, remove, purge, repair it.

```
$ sudo apt-get purge -y docker-ce
...
1 not fully installed or removed.
...
Removing docker-ce (5:20.10.4~3-0~ubuntu-bionic) ...
Job for docker.service canceled.
invoke-rc.d: initscript docker, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing package docker-ce (--remove):
 installed docker-ce package pre-removal script subprocess returned error exit status 1
dpkg: too many errors, stopping
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 installed docker-ce package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 docker-ce
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

There are two possible docker packages to install: docker.io from Debian/Ubuntu and docker-ce from docker.com. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023363/what-is-docker-io-in-relation-to-docker-ce-and-docker-ee) discusses the differences. I had both installed

```
dpkg -l | grep -i docker
```

Looks for me it was choking on `containerd` which would not start. You can check messages in `/var/log/syslog`

Tried many things which did not work

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
$ sudo systemctl list-jobs
$ sudo systemctl disable docker.service
$ sudo systemctl disable containerd.service
$ sudo systemctl stop containerd.service
...
```

Removing folders, uninstalling all docker packages and reinstalling docker.io worked

```
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd/
$ sudo rm -rf /var/lib/docker/
$ sudo apt-get purge -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker.io containerd.io
$ sudo apt-get install docker.io
```